# What is the best way to add a jumper J1 to a circuit, wrt electronic design & simulation (i.e. w KiCAD & ngSpice)

Tags: circuit-design, kicad, ngspice

What is the best way to add a jumper J1 to a circuit, wrt electronic design & simulation (i.e. w KiCAD & ngSpice).?.

I originally tried to add a jumper J1 (symbol type GS2) to my circuit in eSim-2.1 (containing KiCad 4.0.7) on Windows 10 x64:

[image: Working Circuit previous to adding J1 jumper]

... this caused the program to crash... here're the last items in the console window:

```
==================================================

r0 srcpw net-_r0-pad2_ 1k

* u2 srcpw2 plot_v1

r2 gnd srcpw2 7k

r3 srcpw2 net-_r3-pad2_ 1k

v2 net-_r3-pad2_ gnd 10

j1 net-_j1-pad1_ gnd 1

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "projManagement Kicad.py", line 209, in openkicadToNgspice

File "frontEnd\DockArea.py", line 199, in kicadToNgspiceEditor

File "kicadtoNgspice\KicadtoNgspice.py", line 142, __init__

File "kicadtoNgspice\KicadtoNgspice.py", line 157, in createMainwindow

File "kicadtoNgspice\KicadtoNgspice.py", line 207, in createcreateConvertwidget

File "kicadtoNgspice\DeviceModel.py", line 209, in __init__

IndexError: list index out of range
```

… it may be due to user error, or a software bug, I am not sure ... perhaps I simply need correct value the jumper j1 perhaps?.. I’ve tried:

- GS2
- 0 / 1
- open / closed
- false / true

... but they all crash the program.?.

After further research && feedback (*both on here and other forums*), I decided to try the more up-to-date KiCAD 5.1.12_1:

[image: Circuit Schematic in KiCAD 5.1.12_1]

... and I ran into a very similar issue:

```
No compatibility mode selected!
Circuit: KiCad schematic
Error on line 8 :
jp1 net-jp1-pad1 net-jp1-pad2 jumper_2_open
Unable to find definition of model
Error: circuit not parsed.
```

… when trying to run the built-in [Spice Simulator].

Which tends to imply to me that I'm missing something perhaps, vs an inherent software issue.

I can't see I'm the only person who wants a jumper in their schematic, that can then be further consumed by a board layout program, without their simulation failing.

So I'm curious what the 'best practice' is in the industry wrt adding/modeling for jumpers?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're referring to jumpers and a circuit, but there's no indication as to what any of those mean.

Comment: Time for an exorcism on Win 10 and a more rational disclosure of where in the world is that jumper.  Did it violate KVL?

Comment: your schematic is drawn upside down ... please follow convention ... V+ at top, GND at bottom, input on left, output at right

Comment: @Hearth - I designed a circuit in eSim, and it worked correctly "until" I added a jumper J1 of type GS2.  I'm not sure what you mean by, "there's no indication as to what any of those mean".?.  They're in the picture of the circuit, I stated the software used, & my guess is the answer revolves about the "legal values" for a jumper (GS2) in eSim .. so that's why I may / may not be using it's correct values.?.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'm not sure what you mean by the first sentence of your comment (genuinely, not trolling).  Also, I'm not sure why KVL would apply.?.  If it's "open" that part of the circuit is 'off'; if it's "closed", then that part of the circuit would run as before.

Comment: When I asked that, there was no picture of a circuit. I still don't see anything marked as "GS2", though.

Comment: @Hearth in eSim, GS2 is the "type/model/symbol" used for the jumper J1 in the circuit.

Comment: I also have no idea what esim is.

Comment: @Hearth also, sorry you got a copy of the question in the brief minute where I realized I didn't include it.

Comment: @Hearth eSim === https://esim.fossee.in/home === "eSim (previously known as Oscad / FreeEDA) is a free/libre and open source EDA tool for circuit design, simulation, analysis and PCB design. It is an integrated tool built using free/libre and open source software such as KiCad, Ngspice and GHDL. eSim is released under GPL."

Comment: @jsotola I'm not sure why the orientation of the schematic matters to answering the question.?.  but GND is effectively "at the bottom", and my sources have V+ going "up"...  not that it matters, but it was laid out that way so that I could fit other things in later ... but got hung up in the basic learning/testing/setup of the circuit & eSim software.

Answer (score 1):

If the program crashes, then it's a software bug, not an electronics problem. Report it to the developers.

Comment: not all software crashing is due to software bugs, it can also be due to improper use of software (such as an invalid parameter).  I'm hoping someone will be able to confirm/deny what I'm doing is correct (and should what I'm doing be "correct", then I can file a bug report).  But I'm thinking, I can't be the only EE who's tried to use a jumper in eSim; and so hopefully someone who's done it successfully will be able to help.

Comment: It's a bug, it shouldn't crash just because you did something wrong.

Comment: Yes. Especially not crash like this. There is no special knowledge of electronics that lets EEs safely use a jumper without a "list index out of range" error ;) At best it would be knowing the quirks of the software.

Comment: If you're "using it wrong" then there should be an error message about parameters, not a bounds exception, so you are entirely justified in reporting a bug.

Comment: Also, why not just use a switch?

Comment: @DamienD because ideally at some point I'd like to build the circuit (once I built it up to the way I wanted, this was just some initial testing/setup), and should I do that I wanted it to be a jumper (and supposedly eSim will let me do board layout as well).

Comment: @OskarSkog & DamienD ... I understand what you're saying ... but to me an 'unhandled exception' would be (to me) more like a 'baby bug' in some respects, as it might be caused by the user (aka moi) doing something that just wasn't anticipated / trapped.  It could also come from the fact that when I was a EE in college (when  roamed) I remember pspice throwing all types of ugly errors (like the one here) until we learned how to input & format the file inputs correctly.  (I will admit, in an ideal world, I agree "all errors in all software should be trapped", but that's certainly not true.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could be considered a 'best practice'; however, it is a work around I discovered (*at least for KiCAD 5.1.12_1*)...

With a related comment by @franzee (*user on another site*) I eventually figured out a way to solve the issue.

So I was thinking how can I maybe just “copy the model”… and that prompted me to look at the model for the basic resistors in the circuit and the “model” for the jumper… then, I just tried to add the info from the basic resistors to the J1 jumper:

[image: KiCAD 5.1.12_1 workaround settings for a jumper]

And, voila! … success. I tested it with both values of 1e9 (`open`) && 0 (`closed`) and it responded correctly in both regards.  In addition, for completeness sake, another possibility for a `closed` version of the jumper would be to set `Spice_Netlist_Enabled` to `N`...  I'm not sure if that's any better/worse than using a 0 Ohm resistor.?.

I did try to do the same under eSim 2.1 & KiCAD v4.0.7:

[image: KiCAD v4.0.7 unsuccessful settings attempt]

... but I had exactly the same error.  I will note, that the alternate *possibility* from above for a `closed` version of the jumper of setting `Spice_Netlist_Enabled` to `N` ***did*** in fact *work*...  but I don't consider it resolved, since it only works "half way".

But again, I don't know if this is an industry best-practice, or just a hack.?. … i.e. was there an easier way or option I missed?